# Intro page in wordpress for first visit, with htaccess

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to do an introduction page for a website. The trick is, i would only like the user to be redirected here on the first visit. E.g. if he has no session yet. (Although I am not familiar what else to use.) I have been told about .htaccess could do the trick. I use the wordpress engine.

Intro page: http://www.example.com/?page_id=5 (First visitors should be redirected here.)
Index page under: http://www.example.com/ (Should not be changed for the engine's mechanisms. In fact this is a custom page too http://www.example.com/?page_id=1, but was selected to be main page in the wordpress options.)

Can you help me? Can you show me specific htaccess code?

Thanks,
Sziro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you edit your php files? php handles sessions more flexibly than .htaccess.

Basically something simple to put at the top of your header.php (before anything else gets executed).

```
<?php
    $redirect_url = home_url('/?page_id=5');
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['blablabla']) ) {
        $_SESSION['blablabla'] = "blablabla";
        wp_redirect($redirect_url);
    }
?>
```

This way whenever any page is accessed (since wordpress includes the header in requested pages), php checks if the session (specifically $_SESSION['blablabla']) has been set, if not then redirect to the home page.

Comment: @xiankai, how this is going to help if we need to check the very first visit of user, i.e. just after registration ?

Comment: FYI Googlers stumbling upon this: to get rid of the "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error, put this code snippet above the `<?php get_header(); ?>` line in the page.php template instead of header.php

Answer (score 2):

Cookies may be more reliable than session variables in certain situations:

```
<?php
$redirect_url = home_url('/welcomepageurlhere');
    if ($_COOKIE['returningUser'] == '') {
        setcookie('returningUser','1');
        wp_redirect($redirect_url);
    }
?>
```

Place that snippet above the `<?php get_header(); ?>` line in your page.php template.

Comment: I'm not sure how cookies are more reliable than sessions as the latter are stored on the server and thus independent of browser; but should you chose to go down that route, i suggest specifying the 4th argument of [setcookie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) specifically, to ensure that it'll be applicable to the entire domain.

Comment: In my experience I've had issues with sessions timing out server-side and session variables being lost. Cookies don't time out unless you explicitly specify a timeout `setcookie('name', 'val', time () + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);`.  Their reliability has nothing to do with the browser though, you're right, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: You're right in that cookies would be more persistent than server side sessions (which would last for as long the browser is open); which in turn could fit the use case for a one-time redirect, better.